# Consolidating multiple fields into one

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have data that looks similar to this:

```
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|  id  |                          question                          |         response         |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 1234 | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Delivery                 |
| 1234 | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Customer Service         |
| 1234 | What about our Customer Service could we improve?          | Response Time            |
| 1234 | What about our Customer Service could we improve?          | Less Email               |
| 1234 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Table                    |
| 5678 | What about our Customer Service could we improve?          | Response Time            |
| 5678 | What about our Customer Service could we improve?          | Site Navigation          |
| 5678 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Bookshelf                |
| 5678 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Table                    |
| 5678 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Chairs                   |
| 9999 | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Customer Service         |
| 9999 | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Ease of Assembly         |
| 9999 | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Pricing                  |
| 9999 | What about our delivery could we improve?                  | Shipping Time            |
| 9999 | What about our delivery could we improve?                  | Custom Delivery          |
| 9999 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Bookshelf                |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

You will notice that not only is each question its own row, but there's repeating `question` rows by `id` with different answers in `response`. What might be challenging is that there's no consistency between how many responses an ID gives for a question. `5678` gave three answers to `What other products would you like to see us make?` while `9999` only answered one. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the number of answers in which an ID can give to a question will never exceed four. The answers are pre-set from a list.

I would like to format my data in a manner that creates a 1:1 answer between `question` and `response`, as such:

```
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|  id  |                          question                          |                  response                   |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| 1234 | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Delivery, Customer Service                  |
| 1234 | What about our Customer Service could we improve?          | Response Time, Less Email                   |
| 1234 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Table                                       |
| 5678 | What about our Customer Service could we improve?          | Response Time, Site Navigation              |
| 5678 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Bookshelf, Table, Chairs                    |
| 9999 | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Customer Service, Ease of Assembly, Pricing |
| 9999 | What about our delivery could we improve?                  | Shipping Time, Custom Delivery              |
| 9999 | What other products would you like to see us make?         | Bookshelf                                   |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Having the responses be comma seperated would be helpful, but I'm not sure if that has to be done through some form of concatination over a partition or if there's some sort of built in function that can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, question, STRING_AGG(response, ', ') response
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id, question
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1234 id, 'What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?' question, 'Delivery' response UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?', 'Customer Service' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'What about our Customer Service could we improve?', 'Response Time' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'What about our Customer Service could we improve?', 'Less Email' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234, 'What other products would you like to see us make?', 'Table' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5678, 'What about our Customer Service could we improve?', 'Response Time' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5678, 'What about our Customer Service could we improve?', 'Site Navigation' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5678, 'What other products would you like to see us make?', 'Bookshelf' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5678, 'What other products would you like to see us make?', 'Table' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5678, 'What other products would you like to see us make?', 'Chairs' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9999, 'What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?', 'Customer Service' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9999, 'What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?', 'Ease of Assembly' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9999, 'What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?', 'Pricing' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9999, 'What about our delivery could we improve?', 'Shipping Time' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9999, 'What about our delivery could we improve?', 'Custom Delivery' UNION ALL
  SELECT 9999, 'What other products would you like to see us make?', 'Bookshelf' 
)
SELECT id, question, STRING_AGG(response, ', ') response
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id, question
-- ORDER BY id, question
```

with result

```
Row id      question                                                    response     
1   1234    What about our Customer Service could we improve?           Response Time, Less Email    
2   1234    What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?  Delivery, Customer Service   
3   1234    What other products would you like to see us make?          Table    
4   5678    What about our Customer Service could we improve?           Response Time, Site Navigation   
5   5678    What other products would you like to see us make?          Bookshelf, Table, Chairs     
6   9999    What about our delivery could we improve?                   Shipping Time, Custom Delivery   
7   9999    What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?  Customer Service, Ease of Assembly, Pricing  
8   9999    What other products would you like to see us make?          Bookshelf
```